# Map numpy's `in1d` over 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two 2D `numpy` arrays,

```
import numpy as np    
a = np.array([[  1,  15,  16, 200,  10],
              [ -1,  10,  17,  11,  -1],
              [ -1,  -1,  20,  -1,  -1]])

g = np.array([[  1,  12,  15, 100,  11],
              [  2,  13,  16, 200,  12],
              [  3,  14,  17, 300,  13],
              [  4,  17,  18, 400,  14],
              [  5,  20,  19, 500,  16]])
```

What I want to do is, for each column of `g`, to check if it contains any element from the corresponding column of `a`. For the first column, I want to check if any of the values `[1,2,3,4,5]` appears in `[1,-1,-1]` and return `True`. For the second, I want to return `False` because no element in `[12,13,14,17,20]` appears in `[15,10,-1]`. At the moment, I do this using Python's list comprehension. Running

```
 result = [np.any(np.in1d(g[:,i], a[:, i])) for i in range(5)]
```

calculates the correct result, but is getting slow when `a` has a lot of columns. Is there a more "pure `numpy`" way of doing this same thing? I feel like there should be an `axis` keyword one could add to the `numpy.in1d` function, but there isn't any...

Comment: Sorry my answer was incorrect.

Comment: is the number of rows of `a` and `g` small like in the example?

Comment: @GiulioGhirardo Sorry for taking so long to respond: the number of rows of `a` and `g` is much smaller than the number of columns. `g` has at most 10 rows and `a` has at most 100. The number of columns is between 10,000 and 20,000

Comment: run some benchmark with the 3 solutions and see which performs best for your use case. You could report your findings by editing the question.

Comment: @GiulioGhirardo I plan to do that as soon as I get some time to do so, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use broadcasting tricks, but this depends very much on the size of your arrays and the amount of RAM available to you:

```
M = g.reshape(g.shape+(1,)) - a.T.reshape((1,a.shape[1],a.shape[0]))
np.any(np.any(M == 0, axis=0), axis=1)
# returns:
# array([ True, False,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

It's easier to explain with a piece of paper and a pen (and smaller test arrays) (see below), but basically you're making copies of each column in `g` (one copy for each row in `a`) and subtracting single elements taken from the corresponding column in `a` from these copies. Similar to the original algorithm, just vectorized.

*Caveat*: if any of the arrays `g` or `a` is 1D, you'll need to force it to become 2D, such that its shape is at least `(1,n)`.

*Speed gains*:

- based only on your arrays: a factor ~20

  - python for loops: 301us per loop
  - vectorized: 15.4us per loop
- larger arrays: factor ~80

  ```
  In [2]: a = np.random.random_integers(-2, 3, size=(4, 50))

  In [3]: b = np.random.random_integers(-20, 30, size=(35, 50))

  In [4]: %timeit np.any(np.any(b.reshape(b.shape+(1,)) - a.T.reshape((1,a.shape[1],a.shape[0])) == 0, axis=0), axis=1)
  10000 loops, best of 3: 39.5 us per loop

  In [5]: %timeit [np.any(np.in1d(b[:,i], a[:, i])) for i in range(a.shape[1])]
  100 loops, best of 3: 3.13 ms per loop
  ```

Image attached to explain broadcasting:
[image: broadcasting explained]

Comment: watch out claiming performance improvements. It really depends on the data. If you take for your `a,b` the sizes `(4000, 15)` and `(3500, 15)`, which are quite reasonable, your solutions is far slower than mine, and also of the one posted by the OP.

Comment: You're absolutely right, and a fairly large reason for that is the short-circuit evaluation you're using, which comes into play first with the dimensions you chose (number of rows being much larger than the number of columns). But it also depends on the values present in `a` and `g`, as you mention (in the example above, the range of values is fairly limited).

Comment: I like this answer, but don't quite understand. The arrays you subtract, i.e. `g.reshape(g.shape+(1,))` and `a.T.reshape((1,a.shape[1],a.shape[0]))`, they have different shapes. The first is (1,5,3) and the second is (5,5,1). How does subtraction even work in this case?

Comment: @5xum, I've added an image to visualize what is happening in this broadcasting trick. The "flat arrays" you see in the bottom left are the result after the `reshape` and `transpose operations`. When numpy is asked to subtract those arrays it'll broadcast both to become the same shape, by placing repeated copies of itself along the missing axis (axis `-1` or `2` in this case).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of processing the input by column, you can process it by rows. For example you find out if any element of the first row of `a` is present in the columns of `g`, so that you can stop processing the columns where the element is found.

```
idx = arange(a.shape[1])
result = empty((idx.size,), dtype=bool)
result.fill(False)

for j in range(a.shape[0]):
    #delete this print in production
    print "%d line, I look only at columns " % (j + 1), idx
    line_pruned = take(a[j], idx)
    g_pruned = take(g, idx, axis=1)
    positive_idx = where((g_pruned - line_pruned) == 0)[1]
    #delete this print in production
    print "positive hit on the ", positive_idx, " -th columns"
    put(result, positive_idx, True)
    idx = setdiff1d(idx, positive_idx)
    if not idx.size:
        break
```

To understand how it works, we can consider a different input:

```
a = np.array([[  0,  15,  16, 200,  10],
              [ -1,  10,  17,  11,  -1],
              [  1,  -1,  20,  -1,  -1]])

g = np.array([[  1,  12,  15, 100,  11],
              [  2,  13,  16, 200,  12],
              [  3,  14,  17, 300,  13],
              [  4,  17,  18, 400,  14],
              [  5,  20,  19, 500,  16]])
```

The output of the script is:

```
1 line, I look only at columns  [0 1 2 3 4]
positive hit on the  [2 3]  -th columns
2 line, I look only at columns  [0 1 4]
positive hit on the  []  -th columns
3 line, I look only at columns  [0 1 4]
positive hit on the  [0]  -th columns
```

Basically you can see how in the 2nd and 3rd round of the loop you're not processing the 2nd and 4th column.

The performance of this solution really depends on many factors, but it will be faster if it is likely that you hit many `True` values, and the problem has many rows. This of course depends also on the input, not just on the shape.